# ExtJS: focus field

Tags: extjs, focus

I have a window containing a form (formPanel). Users can show this window clicking on a button in an ExtJS environment. I would like that when the user clicks the button to show the window, a specific field inside the form contained by the window will focus (by this I mean that the cursor should move to that field so that the user can insert data without needing to click on the field itself first).

I tried some solutions, but could not get them work. Any hints?

Here is what I tried, using some examples I found... but it does not work as expected. This function() is called by the ExtJS button in my interface:

```
function openCardForm(IDUser){

    //Reset the value of this field which may be still there from the prev. usage
    Ext.getCmp('assignFormCARDNUMBER').reset();
    formAssignCard.getForm().load({ 
        url: 'gen/jsonUser.php',
        params:{IDUser:IDUser},
        waitMsg: 'Loading...'
    });
    //Try to focus the Card field when rendering the form
    Ext.getCmp('assignFormCARDNUMBER').on("render",function(){
        Ext.getCmp('assignFormCARDNUMBER').focus(true,10);
    });
    win.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try on `show` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Actually I finally put the new handler on the show event of the window where the form is inserted. Moreover, I added some delay for focusing the element, which seems to be necessary. The focusing code became: Ext.getCmp('assignFormCARDNUMBER').focus(true,800);

Answer (score 3):

Or Use

```
defaultButton : yourComponentToFocusOn
```

A bit confusing but the defaultButton can be any component (not necessary to be an actual button)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try setting the tabindex of the field to zero in its config options...that way you wont even need to add a listener to detect the show event.

ie:

```
tabIndex:0
```

Comment: It should be noted that there have been substantial changes to the framework since the original question/answer